# How to scale a mesh without changing the position?

Tags: javascript, three.js, scale

I have in this scene 27 meshes, each of which has an associated number. The one with the highest number will have the scale 1. The rest will have a value less than 1 successively.

Next I want it to climb each of the loops accordingly. My problem occurs when the position of each mesh is changed.

Indeed it is scaled to the size that is due, but it changes position. I'm struggling as several screens are stacking.

[image]

I just need you to climb and stay in the same position as in this example:

[image]

US states are scaled, but still keeping their position. I think that they scale to the center of the figure.

I created the meshes (each called "municipios")

```js
for(var s=0; s< features.features[x].geometry.coordinates[0].length; s=s+1){                       
   geometria[x].vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3((((features.features[x].geometry.coordinates[0][s][0])+75.5)*10),(((features.features[x].geometry.coordinates[0][s][1])-5.5)*10),0));                                   
}
forma_figura[x]=new THREE.Shape(geometria[x].vertices);
extrude_geometria[x]=new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(forma_figura[x],datos_extrusion);
municipios[x] = new THREE.Mesh( extrude_geometria[x], materialExtrude[x] );
scene.add(municipios[x]);

// so I change the scale:
//formula is the value of scale. The biggest number has escale 1.
new TWEEN.Tween(municipios[x].scale).to({ x: formula, y: formula  }, 1000).start();
//this ultimate line is the same:    municipios[x].scale.set(formula,formula,formula);
```

Comment: so they are normally before changing the scale. http://i.imgur.com/okQQ5Ue.png?1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the mesh position is not at its center, or whatever reference you want it to be : if you create a geometry with average vertices `x` component over 100, its visible position will be its real position plus (100,0,0). If you did not specify a position for the mesh ((0,0,0) by default), it will look being at (100,0,0) precisely. Scaling it by .5 for instance will result in the average position being at (100,0,0)*.5=(50,0,0), making the mesh apparently change its position.

What needs to be done is :

- to substract the coordinates of the center from all the vertices. Vertices are inside the **geometry**, so once it is done, `geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true` needs to be set.
- then to add the coordinates of the center to the **mesh**, to compensate.

So the resulting mesh will be positionned at its center without having moved.

There are three different possibilities to define the center :

- Three.js can center your mesh automatically based on the **center of the bounding box** with `geometry.center()` and `THREE.GeometryUtils.center(geometry)`.
- You can compute the **centroid** by looping through the vertices a first time to get their average coordinates.
- You may neither want the center of the bouding box, nor the centroid, but a **custom center**. For example if you are scaling 'people' meshes and want their feet touch the ground at any scale : on the horizontal plane the center you want can be one of the two first, but its vertical coordinate must be the lowest vertical coordinate found (the very bottom of the feet).

Of course if your meshes are imported from a 3D editor software you can also do that inside it.

Comment: I excuse my ignorance but I do not understand. I understood that I must move all the mesh point of the local coordinates 0,0,0. http://i.imgur.com/jXM7t63.png. I did this:

Comment: municipios[i].position.x  = offsetArray[i].x;
municipios[i].position.y  = offsetArray[i].y 
municipios[i].position.z  = offsetArray[i].z; // offsetArray [i] 0,0,0 is local to each mesh.

Comment: with all that I get put in 0,0,0, after I apply the scale for each mesh and finally  i did: municipios[i].translate.x=0;
municipios[i].translate.y=0;
municipios[i].translate.z=0;

Comment: but now it is in the same position. what am I doing wrong?. Sorry, but I think you did not understand. and excuse my ignorance.

Comment: Indeed i may not understand. If you can correct your syntax it may get more clear, basic words like 'you' are used for 'meshes'. I re-read again and understand the same thing. I write another example to explain what i meant : say you have a geometry of only one vector at `(-1,0,0)`. You create the mesh : `mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material ); scene add( mesh );`. Your mesh position is `(0,0,0)`. But your vertex is 1 unit away in the negative x axis. Scaling it by 2 will get this vertex at position `(-2,0,0)`, as if your mesh had moved 1 unit, while it is still at the origin.

Comment: thank you. excuse my syntax not speak good English. I more or less understand. in my case that is what should I do ?. each mesh that I have will have a different scale in successive order. one will be the largest in scale 1. The following scale will be less than 1 and so on.

Comment: each mesh is in the 0,0,0 position. I think they are relative positions. in my case I should do ?. I have not even clear. forgive my ignorance.

Comment: Some good practices : 1. please write one comment with all your questions and wait the answer. 2. Edit your comment if you need to add something, don't add two others. 3. Re-read yourself, your english is not bad but you mess basic words, showing you just don't care about the ones you're asking for help. 4. The problem you describe in your last comment is exactly the one my post answers to :) I can't help you more.

Comment: Okay. Pardon my ignorance. I'm new to this community. already for next time I should not do. not all people understand the same level. although it is obvious to you, do not understand that I must believe me hacer.y although you have answered me, I am not clear what to do. I'd appreciate if you focus on what I have in my code to understand it better. I seriously do not grasp what you trying to tell me to correct my problem.please help me last time.

Comment: Look, I still do not understand, you can be a little more specific based on my code, I do what I think I understand. but it does not work.

Comment: See [Related chat in spanish - translation at the end](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89972/three-js-help-in-spanish). This question was solved in this chat, so feel free to check it out.